# Problems getting a WiFii hotspot working on a Raspberry Pi using an external Wi-Fi module

Tags: wireless-networking, raspberry-pi

I am trying to create a hotspot on a Raspberry Pi (raspbian) using an external Wi-Fi module (wg2017).

I tried [`nmcli`](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nmcli.html) to create one but `nmcli` doesn't see `wlan0`.

```
wlan0  wifi      unavailable  --
```

I tried using a solution that includes disabling [`dhcpcd`](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=179576) and created the hotspot but I can not connect to that network. Because after disabling `dhcpcd` I can not get an IP address.

I tried a solution that includes `hostapd` but in that situation I cannot see the Wi-Fi device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there are other ways to make this work, but I would suggest to stick with the [official guide](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md) by the Raspberry Pi foundation for creating an access point.

Then you can be sure that it will work out with Raspbian.

A few notes/hints to your setup:

- An external Wi-Fi module will typically show up as `wlan1`. Make sure to replace `wlan0` with `wlan1` (or the name of the actual interface, if it indeed differs from `wlan1`) in the linked tutorial above.
- Getting `network-manager` to work an Raspbian is not straightforward. Simply installing `network-manager` will not cut it. Please see e.g. [this questions](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/29783/how-to-setup-network-manager-on-raspbian/73816#73816).
- As you already seem to have tried several different things to make this work, I would suggest to start off with a fresh Raspbian image, if this is not too inconvenient for you. Otherwise even the official tutorial might not work due to side-effects from changes made to your system.

Comment: Yes that actually worked. With a little bit of trial and error.